# How do I remove spaces when creating a CSV document

Tags: cobol

I have program that creates a CSV document. One field from a database table, `Z-ZYSR-MONTAN(IZYSR)`, has the format `NOT NULL NUMBER(11,2)`.

My code is :

```
      05  H-ZYSR-MONTAN           PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3.

* Taux horaire formation
      05  W-Z18                  PIC -(12),99.
      05  FILLER                 PIC X(001) VALUE ';'.
 ALIM-WZ18 SECTION.
     MOVE Z-ZYSR-NOMBRE TO IZYSR.
     MOVE ZERO TO H-ZYSR-MONTAN.

     IF Z-ZYSR-NOMBRE > ZERO
         PERFORM VARYING IZYSR FROM Z-ZYSR-NOMBRE BY -1 UNTIL
                                 IZYSR = ZERO
              IF Z-ZYSR-CODRUB(IZYSR) = 'THF'
                   MOVE Z-ZYSR-MONTAN(IZYSR) TO
                        H-ZYSR-MONTAN
                   MOVE ZERO TO IZYSR
              END-IF
         END-PERFORM
         IF H-ZYSR-MONTAN < 0
              MOVE 0 TO W-Z18
         END-IF
         IF H-ZYSR-MONTAN >= 0
              MOVE H-ZYSR-MONTAN TO W-Z18
         END-IF
     END-IF.
```

Results:

```
    2223,55
     -10,98
      -1,08
      82,61
```

But the problem I have in my CSV document is that there are spaces before the number. As may be seen in the picture in this forum :

https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1940330/autres-langages/autres-langages/cobol/numerique-condense-cobol/#post10895608

So my question how can I obtain the correct results without spaces before the number?

Comment: You should experiment with MOVEL in stead of MOVE in the place where the leading spaces are created.

Comment: disn't work i have error : Illegal format : Literal

Comment: Normally in z/OS IBM Enterprise COBOL you get leading zeroes. You can suppress them with a Z, or for cheque processing you can replace them with an asterisk.

PIC Z(11)9,99 would give you zero supression (so you'd get leading spaces).
PIC * would give you leading asterisks.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rlddezsr.htm

You're NOT seeeing that which is puzzling. What platform are you working on? z/OS, Windows, Linux?

Comment: if i put PIC Z(11)9,99 i will obtain 0 before my values , like 002,66 or 0055889,88 but in my results i want 2,66 , 5,96 and without spaces. i am working in linux , HRAccess , i have a program cobol with cart parametres

Comment: i am trying to used DELIMITED BY but i obtain error also

Comment: OK, so in some COBOLs you can do a MOVE of a substring, provided you know when you want to start and how long it is. You'd need to move the number to a "numeric-edited" field though.

"         12,66" is nine spaces then the number. That might be moved as

MOVE NEW-FIELD(10:5) TO OUTPUT-FIELD

that's start at the 10th character for a length of 5.

If you want to count how many zeroes are at the start of a numeric edited field, I think you can use the INSPECT my-field TALLYING some-count for LEADING '0'.

Not 100% sure of syntax but I've done something similar. You can then substring.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation and other information, I changed the code a little bit. I removed all references to CSV, since that seems to occur outside the COBOL program. I replaced the `STRING` statement. The data-name for the group containing `W-Z18` and the `;` was not given in other references, so here I named it, `W-Z18-FIELD`. I placed the result in `W-Z18-TEXT`.

```
   environment division.
   configuration section.
   special-names.
       decimal-point is comma.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 w-z18-text pic x(16) value space.
   1 w-z18-pointer comp pic 9(4) value 1.
   1 w-z18-field.
  * Taux horaire formation
     3 w-z18 pic -(12),99.
     3 pic x value ";".
   1 leading-spaces comp pic 9(4) value 0.
   1 move-length comp pic 9(4) value 0.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       move -10,98 to w-z18
       move 0 to leading-spaces
       inspect w-z18 tallying
           leading-spaces for leading space
       compute move-length =
           function length (w-z18 (leading-spaces + 1:))
       move space to w-z18-text
       move 1 to w-z18-pointer
       move w-z18 (leading-spaces + 1:)
           to w-z18-text (w-z18-pointer:move-length)
       compute w-z18-pointer = w-z18-pointer + move-length
       move ";" to w-z18-text (w-z18-pointer:1)
       add 1 to w-z18-pointer
       display quote w-z18-field quote
       display quote w-z18-text quote
       stop run
       .
```

Result: (the quotes were added to show the change)

```
"         -10,98;" - what it looked like before, w-z18-field
"-10,98;         " - with the changes, w-z18-text
```

This only moves the spaces from before the number to after the semi-colon. Whether this will be enough depends on whether the next program removes trailing spaces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192114/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-smith-how-do-i-remove-spaces-when-creating-a-csv-do).

Comment: the cobol program retrieves the data from the database and is formatted as requested , for that i have alot of variable like W-Z18 , w-Z19 .... itts the same that i declare in my parameter carte

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRIM() function to remove white space if you're using GnuCOBOL(OpenCOBOL) on Linux.

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01.
       05  H-ZYSR-MONTAN           PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3.
       05  W-Z18                   PIC -(12).99.
       05  H-Z18-C REDEFINES W-Z18 PIC X(15).
       05  H-ZYSR-DISPLAY          PIC X(15).


   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   0000-MAIN.

       MOVE 1234.56 TO H-ZYSR-MONTAN.
       move H-ZYSR-MONTAN to W-Z18.

       MOVE FUNCTION TRIM(H-Z18-C) TO H-ZYSR-DISPLAY.
       DISPLAY H-ZYSR-DISPLAY.

       STOP RUN.
```

I did have to change the , to . to match my locale so remember to change it back.

And if you don't have access to that function there is a simple work around.

```
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01.
           05  H-ZYSR-MONTAN           PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3.
           05  W-Z18                   PIC -(12).99.
           05  VAR-Z18                 PIC X(15).
           05  ws-counter              pic 9(3) COMP-3 value 0.

       01 VARIABLES.
           05 VAR1                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR2                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR3                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR4                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR5                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR6                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR7                     PIC X(10).
           05 VAR8                     PIC X(10).

       01 WS-DELIMITED-TEXT            PIC X(200).

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       0000-MAIN.

           INITIALIZE VARIABLES
           MOVE 'CEX18'  TO VAR6
           MOVE -1234.56 TO H-ZYSR-MONTAN 

           MOVE H-ZYSR-MONTAN TO W-Z18
           INSPECT W-Z18 TALLYING WS-COUNTER FOR LEADING SPACES
           IF WS-COUNTER > 0 
              COMPUTE WS-COUNTER = WS-COUNTER + 1
              MOVE W-Z18(ws-counter:) TO VAR-Z18
           ELSE 
               MOVE W-Z18             TO VAR-Z18
           END-IF

           String VAR1 delimited by SPACE
                   ";" delimited by size
                  VAR2 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size   
                  VAR3 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size   
                  VAR4 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size  
                  VAR5 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size  
                  VAR6 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size  
                   VAR-Z18 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size  
                  VAR7 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size  
                  VAR8 delimited by SPACE
                  ";" delimited by size  
            into WS-DELIMITED-TEXT
            DISPLAY WS-DELIMITED-TEXT.

           GOBACK.
```

Using STRING to assemble the final text field was already suggested by the other forum I only include it here to round out the example.

Comment: i do my move after if ?

Comment: 05  H-Z18-C REDEFINES W-Z18 PIC X(15).
* 204-S********************************                                (   0)**
**    REDEFINES on incorrect field
                      MOVE FUNCTION TRIM(H-Z18-C) TO H-ZYSR-DISPLAY.
*  72-S*********************************                               (  39)**
**    Invalid FUNCTION name TRIM

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a loop (PERFORM UNTIL), for every character, and if it is SPACE, then change it by 0.

Comment: how i can make loop

Comment: You can use "PERFORM UNTIL", here you have an example:

`MOVE ZEROES TO IND01
PERFORM UNTIL IND01 > 10
    ADD 1 TO LI
    IF MY-NUMER-VAR(IND01) = SPACE
    MOVE ZEROES TO MY-NUMER-VAR(IND01)
 END-IF
END-PERFORM`

Comment: i can not do this with my program i think that it's difficul

Comment: Then I cannot help you, my friend.